# Construct a matrix in R identifying matching values in a vector

Tags: r, matrix

In R, I have a vector of length `N` of discrete values:

```
A <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
```

I would like to yield an `NxN` matrix of boolean values indicating the vector positions that share a value. Example result:

```
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

(I am hoping to use this matrix as a mask). I can achieve this result using `sapply`:

```
sapply(A, function(b) b == A)
```

But I am wondering if there is a more direct method that doesn't involve a loop or an `apply` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outer` is the function you want:

```
outer(A, A, "==")
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Of course any function will use a loop at some point under the hood, but this is optimized for binary operations on vectors to create matrices, so it should be well-optimized in this case.